# scientific logical puzzle theme for secondary students

Tags: puzzle-creation, science

I'm an university student doing an internship on escape room. Can you please give me some ideas/ theme relating to mathematics or science ?

Comment: Andrea Gilbert has a bunch of mazes many of which can be adapted. I've seen them with paving stones in a garden. But some with more physical boundaries would probably work. http://clickmazes.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think a good escape room puzzle format would be that of the Logic Puzzle Grid; an example can be seen below.

[image]

These grids are often coupled with clues such as "Simon has 15 jars" and "Jane doesn't have Green Labels" which have been used in the example image above.

For a maths/science themed puzzle, there could be the names of famous scientist/mathematicians (e.g. Einstein, Newton, Faraday, Pythagoras, Archimedes) and they have certain lab equipment each (e.g. Ruler, Bunsen Burner, Power Supply, Calculator, Petri Dish) in different coloured storage boxes (e.g. Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Purple).

You could then have the clues that point towards the answers dotted around the room in books on on a blackboard etc. With an image of the empty grid on an overhead projector slide, which, when complete and pointed at a map on the wall reveals the correct locations from a list of locations in a book that has numbers next to the locations, the correct ones are then used for a combination lock to another puzzle etc.

Hope this can help. :D